Reusing FFF Fakes across multiple testsuite files encounters Linker error for _reset functions
I want to create a single test executable that is comprised of several .cc files each one representing a different testsuite. I am using gtest as the framework and Fake Function Framework(FFF) to fake C library calls. I am trying to define the fakes in one .h/.c file and then use that in the different test suites. I am running into an issue with calling the reset function of the fake.
Fake Header
#pragma once

#include "fff.h"
#include "osdp.h"

DECLARE_FAKE_VALUE_FUNC(osdp_t*, osdp_cp_setup, int, const osdp_pd_info_t *);
DECLARE_FAKE_VOID_FUNC(osdp_cp_teardown, osdp_t *);
...

// List of fakes used by these unit tests
#define FFF_FAKES_LIST(FUNC)            \
    FUNC(osdp_cp_setup)                 \
    FUNC(osdp_cp_teardown)              \
    ...

Fake Implementation
#include "FakeLibosdp.h"

DEFINE_FFF_GLOBALS

DEFINE_FAKE_VALUE_FUNC(osdp_t*, osdp_cp_setup, int, const osdp_pd_info_t *);
DEFINE_FAKE_VOID_FUNC(osdp_cp_teardown, osdp_t *);
...

Use in testcase setup. I have another testsuite file that is similar and uses the fakes as well.
#include "FakeLibosdp.h"
#include "MockSerial.hh"

class OsdpPdACRTest : public ::testing::Test {
protected:
    void SetUp() {
        // Register resets
        
        // Linker can't find <fake name>_reset function
        FFF_FAKES_LIST(RESET_FAKE);
        // This also doesn't work
        RESET_FAKE(osdp_pd_notify_event);

        // Reset common FFF internal structures
        FFF_RESET_HISTORY();
    }
};
...

If I comment out the FFF_FAKES_LIST() or RESET_FAKE the code compiles and runs but fails because I cannot reset the fakes between test cases. If I leave it in I get the error
x86_64-buildroot-linux-gnu_sdk-buildroot/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-buildroot-linux-gnu/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-buildroot-linux-gnu/bin/ld: tests/gtests/module/osdp/CMakeFiles/test-osdp.dir/test-osdp-pd-acreader.cc.o: in function `OsdpPdACRTest::SetUp()':
/tests/gtests/module/osdp/test-osdp-pd-acreader.cc:17: undefined reference to `osdp_pd_notify_event_reset()'

In my CMakeLists.txt I added FakeLibosdp.h to the include path and FakeLibosdp.c as a source file to the executable. I saw on the FFF github the example of compiling the fakes into a library then linking an application, that would probably work here but seems unnecessary and strange everything is working but resets.
Update

I looked at FakeLibosdp.o which had the appropriate _reset functions that the linker couldn't find. Doing some searching based off that information, I found similar linking problems caused by C/C++ name mangling. Adding extern "C" to the header file did the trick.
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

DECLARE_FAKE_VALUE_FUNC(osdp_t*, osdp_cp_setup, int, const osdp_pd_info_t *);
DECLARE_FAKE_VOID_FUNC(osdp_cp_teardown, osdp_t *);
...

// List of fakes used by these unit tests
#define FFF_FAKES_LIST(FUNC)            \
    FUNC(osdp_cp_setup)                 \
    FUNC(osdp_cp_teardown)              \
    ...
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

